# How do I pass a String to return an object in a get method? web API with ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I'm trying to pass in a string,sigla do Curso, and use the get method to return the object equivalent to this acronym, but the output returns an error

Error:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-8db2fbce7dfcc684ce94f0e8b4baaab1-67a764080f12fca7-00",
"errors": {
    "id": [
        "The value 'enc' is not valid."
    ]
}
```

}

Code:

```
// GET: api/Cursos/LES
        [HttpGet("cursos/{sigla}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Curso>> GetCurso(string sigla)
        {
            if (_context.Cursos == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var curso = await _context.Cursos.Include(f => f.Sigla).
            FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Sigla == sigla);

            
            if (curso == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return curso;
        }
```

Class curso:

```
namespace UniversidadeApi.Models
{
    public class Curso
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string? Sigla { get; set; }
        public string? Nome { get; set; }
 
    }
}
```

URL used to send a get request:
https://localhost:7225/api/cursos/enc

I also tested with the urls:
https://localhost:7225/api/cursos/ENC
https://localhost:7225/api/cursos/"ENC"

The object I created with the post method:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "sigla": "ENC",
    "nome": "Engenharia da Computação"
}
```

Comment: You will have to post the code to show how are your trying to pass a string,sigla do Curso,

Comment: Firstly, please post which url you have used to send the get request.

Comment: I have added some extra information

Comment: Do you have any custom validators on either GetCurso or the Controller containing it?

Comment: no, there is no custom validation

Comment: I have written a test sample with your codes and it works well. Could you please share sample project inside the github to let us test? Just from these codes, we couldn't find any issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[FromRoute]` attribute with your parameter. Like this:

```cs
[HttpGet("cursos/{sigla}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Curso>> GetCurso([FromRoute] string sigla)
{
...
}
```

More about model binding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

I just change the var curso line to this new line and it worked

```
var curso = await _context.Cursos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Sigla == sigla);
```